# Need Guidance on using Blazor, and updating UI with status from extension method

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am creating a bulk image processing app using a hybrid Blazor app.   When a user uploads a set of images, a series of methods get fired to resize them to various resolutions and optimize them.

I would like to realtime/continuously update the UI as the progress of these resizing and optimization advances.

What is the general syntax for updating the Blazor UI with model data that is returned from this method?  None of the samples I have seen so far show this updating of UI with the server-side executed code.

**UPDATE:**

This is my page HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Upload</h2>
    <form id="UploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Upload" asp-antiforgery="false" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="dropzone" id="DropzoneArea"></div>
        <div class="dropzone-fallback" style="display: none;">
            <label id="FilesLabel" for="Files" class="sr-only">Files</label>
            <input type="file" id="Files" name="files" required multiple class="w-100" placeholder="File to optimize..." data-validation-require="Please select a file to squeeze and slice!" />
        </div>
        <button id="UploadButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropzone-upload">Upload</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul id="statusList"></ul>
</div>
```

My post action calls this method:

```
private bool InitializeProcessing(List<IFormFile> files) 
{
    Parallel.ForEach(files.Where(f => f.ContentType.Contains("jpeg") || f.ContentType.Contains("png")), file =>
    {
        List<ImageModel> imageList = ImageRequestExtensions.GetImageModelList(file);
        List<ProcessedImageModel> processedImageList = ImageRequestExtensions.GetProcessedImageModelList(imageList, cache);
    });
    return true;
}
```

It is within the `ImageRequestExtensions.GetProcessedImageModelList` method, I would like to asynchronously add items to the `statusList` UL in the HTML:

```
public static List<ProcessedImageModel> GetProcessedImageModelList(List<ImageModel> input, IMemoryCache cache)
{
    List<ProcessedImageModel> outputList = new List<ProcessedImageModel>();
    foreach (ImageModel image in input)
    {
        List<ProcessedImageModel> processedImageList = ImageManipulationExtensions.Process(image, cache);
        outputList.AddRange(processedImageList);
// WANT TO UPDATE UI HERE
    }
    return outputList;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is about Blazor?  You seem to be navigating away to a Home/Upload mvc page.

Comment: It is posting to an MVC Endpoint.   As the methods execute, I want to asynchronously update the original page's UI without reloading the page.    It doesn't need to be Blazor, it just seemed from the marketing speak that it was capable of doing something similar.